# HTML bulleted text margin, not lining up

Tags: html

I have a bulleted list using HTML and I would like the words to line up if the sentence goes on to two lines. If the text goes to the second row, it lines up with the bullets. I would like it to line up with the text.

Here is what I mean:

[Bullet Text Example](http://www.gefiltefist.com/bullets.jpg)

And here is the code that I am using:

[Bullet Text Code](http://www.gefiltefist.com/bullet.txt)

Comment: Whoa! Get rid of all that horrible inline styling!

Comment: You code works as expected in my browser (Firefox 13)...

Comment: Why not simply use a decent, normal unordered list like any sane person?

Comment: To make the html better readable, I suggest to use tabs/indents to make it look nested and use lower-case letters in your tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code is horrible! If you need similar styling for all list items, use a general stylesheet for all of them! There's no reason for the inner divs and spans!

```
<style type="text/css">
    li {
        font-size: 14pt;
        font-family: "Times New Roman", sans-serif;
    }
</style>
<ul>
    <li> event will be held from 10am - 5pm bring your dog with</li>
    <li> $8 entrance fee (print out your flyer that you received and bring it with you to support your favorite rescue
    </li>
    (kids under 12 are free) $5 of you entrance fee will go to that dog rescue or organization </li>
    <li> must bring current vaccination paperwork, no exceptions, dogs will not be allowed in without this paperwork
    </li>
    <li> no firearms, alcoholic beverages, outside food or drink, coolers or glass containers</li>
    <li> bags will be checked prior to entrance</li>
    <li> event will be photographed &amp; videotaped</li>
    <li> all dogs must have rabies tags attached to collars</li>
    <li> collars must be worn at all times, no metal collars of any kind allowed</li>
    <li> owners/handlers are legally responsible for the behavior/actions of their dogs</li>
    <li> only 1 dog allowed per adult handler</li>
    <li> dogs must be healthy, fully immunized, de-wormed, &amp; wearing id tags</li>
    <li> female dogs in heat are not permitted</li>
    <li> dogs must be leashed at all times unless in dog play area, owners must watch their dog in this area at all
        times
    </li>
    <li> owners must immediately clean up after their dogs, with a paper or plastic bag</li>
    <li> aggressive dogs will be asked to leave</li>
    <li> muzzled dogs not allowed</li>
    <li> owners must keep their dogs under control at all times</li>
    <li> children must be closely supervised</li>
    <li> please dispose of cigarette butts in proper areas, smoking not allowed in any building</li>
    <li> people who do not follow the rules will be asked to leave immediately</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The end of your code is slightly wrong. You should close your `<\li>` before your `<\ul>`, not the other way around. Try this:

```
<TABLE style="BORDER-COLLAPSE: collapse; MARGIN-RIGHT: 8px">
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD>
<UL>
<LI>
<DIV align=justify><SPAN style="FONT-SIZE: 14pt"><SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: Times New Roman; FONT-SIZE: 14pt">Event will be held from 10am - 5pm Bring Your Dog With</SPAN></SPAN> </DIV>
<LI>
<DIV align=justify><SPAN style="FONT-SIZE: 14pt"><SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: Times New Roman; FONT-SIZE: 14pt">$8 Entrance Fee (print out your flyer that you received and bring it with you to support your favorite Rescue (kids under 12 are FREE) $5 of you entrance fee will go to that dog rescue or organization</SPAN></SPAN> </DIV>
<LI>
<DIV align=justify><SPAN style="FONT-SIZE: 14pt"><SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: Times New Roman; FONT-SIZE: 14pt">MUST bring Current Vaccination Paperwork, NO EXCEPTIONS, dogs will not be allowed in without this paperwork</SPAN></SPAN></DIV>
<LI>
<DIV align=justify><SPAN style="FONT-SIZE: 14pt"><SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: Times New Roman; FONT-SIZE: 14pt">No firearms, alcoholic beverages, outside food or drink, coolers or glass containers</SPAN></SPAN></DIV>
<LI>
<DIV align=justify><SPAN style="FONT-SIZE: 14pt"><SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: Times New Roman; FONT-SIZE: 14pt">Bags will be checked prior to entrance</SPAN></SPAN></DIV>
<LI>
<DIV align=justify><SPAN style="FONT-SIZE: 14pt"><SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: Times New Roman; FONT-SIZE: 14pt">Event will be photographed &amp; videotaped</SPAN></SPAN></DIV>
<LI>
<DIV align=justify><SPAN style="FONT-SIZE: 14pt"><SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: Times New Roman; FONT-SIZE: 14pt">All dogs MUST have rabies tags attached to collars</SPAN></SPAN></DIV>
<LI>
<DIV align=justify><SPAN style="FONT-SIZE: 14pt"><SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: Times New Roman; FONT-SIZE: 14pt">Collars MUST be worn at all times, NO METAL COLLARS of any kind&nbsp;allowed</SPAN></SPAN></DIV>
<LI>
<DIV align=justify><SPAN style="FONT-SIZE: 14pt"><SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: Times New Roman; FONT-SIZE: 14pt">Owners/Handlers are legally responsible for the behavior/actions of their dogs</SPAN></SPAN></DIV>
<LI>
<DIV align=justify><SPAN style="FONT-SIZE: 14pt"><SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: Times New Roman; FONT-SIZE: 14pt">Only 1 dog allowed per adult handler</SPAN></SPAN></DIV>
<LI>
<DIV align=justify><SPAN style="FONT-SIZE: 14pt"><SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: Times New Roman; FONT-SIZE: 14pt">Dogs must be healthy, fully immunized, de-wormed, &amp; wearing ID tags</SPAN></SPAN></DIV>
<LI>
<DIV align=justify><SPAN style="FONT-SIZE: 14pt"><SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: Times New Roman; FONT-SIZE: 14pt">Female dogs in heat are NOT permitted</SPAN> </SPAN></DIV>
<LI>
<DIV align=justify><SPAN style="FONT-SIZE: 14pt"><SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: Times New Roman; FONT-SIZE: 14pt">Dogs MUST be leashed at all times unless in dog play area, owners must watch their dog in this area at all times</SPAN></SPAN> </DIV>
<LI>
<DIV align=justify><SPAN style="FONT-SIZE: 14pt"><SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: Times New Roman; FONT-SIZE: 14pt">Owners MUST IMMEDIATELY clean up after their dogs, with a paper or plastic bag</SPAN> </SPAN></DIV>
<LI>
<DIV align=justify><SPAN style="FONT-SIZE: 14pt"><SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: Times New Roman; FONT-SIZE: 14pt">AGGRESSIVE dogs will be asked to leave</SPAN> </SPAN></DIV>
<LI>
<DIV align=justify><SPAN style="FONT-SIZE: 14pt"><SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: Times New Roman; FONT-SIZE: 14pt">MUZZLED dogs NOT allowed</SPAN> </SPAN></DIV>
<LI>
<DIV align=justify><SPAN style="FONT-SIZE: 14pt"><SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: Times New Roman; FONT-SIZE: 14pt">Owners MUST keep their dogs under control at all times</SPAN> </SPAN></DIV>
<LI>
<DIV align=justify><SPAN style="FONT-SIZE: 14pt"><SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: Times New Roman; FONT-SIZE: 14pt">Children MUST be closely supervised</SPAN></SPAN> </DIV>
<LI>
<DIV align=justify><SPAN style="FONT-SIZE: 14pt"><SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: Times New Roman; FONT-SIZE: 14pt">Please dispose of cigarette butts in proper areas, smoking not allowed in any building</SPAN> </SPAN></DIV>
<LI>
<DIV align=justify><SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: Times New Roman; FONT-SIZE: 14pt">People who do not follow the rules will be asked to leave immediately</SPAN> </DIV>
</LI></UL></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE></DIV>
```

Answer (score 0):

you dont need any divs. You just need to style your `ul`'s.  Like so:

```
ul.out{
 list-style:disc outside none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close every single LI tag..

instead of this:

```
<LI>
<DIV align=justify><SPAN style="FONT-SIZE: 14pt"><SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: Times New Roman; FONT-SIZE: 14pt">Event will be held from 10am - 5pm Bring Your Dog With</SPAN></SPAN> </DIV>
<LI>
<DIV align=justify><SPAN style="FONT-SIZE: 14pt"><SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: Times New Roman; FONT-SIZE: 14pt">$8 Entrance Fee (print out your flyer that you received and bring it with you to support your favorite Rescue (kids under 12 are FREE) $5 of you entrance fee will go to that dog rescue or organization</SPAN></SPAN> </DIV>
```

go with this:

```
<LI>
<DIV align=justify><SPAN style="FONT-SIZE: 14pt"><SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: Times New Roman; FONT-SIZE: 14pt">Event will be held from 10am - 5pm Bring Your Dog With</SPAN></SPAN> </DIV>
</LI>
<LI>
<DIV align=justify><SPAN style="FONT-SIZE: 14pt"><SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: Times New Roman; FONT-SIZE: 14pt">$8 Entrance Fee (print out your flyer that you received and bring it with you to support your favorite Rescue (kids under 12 are FREE) $5 of you entrance fee will go to that dog rescue or organization</SPAN></SPAN> </DIV>
</LI>
```

also, try to keep your tags lower case.

I am not certain, but I believe it is recommended.

To make sure the lines just go on, instead of break to the next line, try setting this:

```
ul {
overflow: auto;
}
```

in your css